# How to incorporate outside information to estimate a coefficient of a variable in dynamic regression for forecasting sales

Tags: time-series, bayesian, forecasting

I am working with a client who wants to forecast sales at the end of Q4 2017, based upon the expected results of a marketing campaign in Q4. The client has 2 years of marketing time-series data for TV and Paid Search as well as 2 years of sales data. Building a dynamic regression forecast model would be straight forward.
However,In Q4, the client will be introducing Radio to the marketing mix. We have an idea of how Radio should be expected to perform relative to say TV, we can look at the fact that Radio typically has 70% of the impact of TV on sales. But how do we incorporate this information into a regression/statistical model when we don't have the historical data to estimate the coefficient on radio.

What type of literature/ models should I investigate in order to understand how to do this?
By the way, I will be either using R or EXCEL to build this model.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: You might want to use intervention analysis but you need to have data before and after the intervention. The data that you do have may help you to form the model structure including seasonal effects. This could also depend on the product which you have not mentioned.

Comment: Your name sounds familiar. Have you written books on methodology?